# Where can I ask a question about tourism in Greece?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

This question was voted off-topic in TSE...

[Preparing for Greece to Exit the EU (Grexit)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49757/preparing-for-greece-to-exit-the-eu-grexit)

It involves difficulties that may be confronting tourists to Greece this summer, specifically that ATM's may not be working and credit card payments may be subject to unregulated exchange rates.

[image]

I think the question has value, if not on TSE, perhaps on another Stack Exchange site. Can anyone direct me to the appropriate SE site where it would be received as topical?

Answer (score 1):

I voted to reopen since it's in my opinion a valid event-based travel question. It should therefore have it's place on TSE regardless of the speculation with respect to the likelihood of grexit actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone on [Money SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/) can help